# How do I correct ansible playbook syntax error?

Tags: ansible, yaml

I am creating an ansible playbook in centos7. I get the syntax error every-time I adjust to the syntax error (I even checked spacing and still getting same error):

ERROR! We were unable to read either as JSON nor YAML, these are the errors we got from each:
JSON: No JSON object could be decoded

Syntax Error while loading YAML.
could not find expected ':'

The error appears to be in '/etc/ansible/playbook.yml': line 121, column 5, but may
be elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.

The offending line appears to be:

```
- name: Install MySQL repo
^ here


 hosts: local host 
 connection: local 
 vars: digital_ocean_token: ****
    droplets:
    - wordpress1
    - wordpress2
 
 tasks:

 - name: Create SSH Key
   user: 
   name: "{{ansible_user_id}}"
   generate_ssh_key_type: rsa
   ssh_key_type 4096
   ssh_key_file .ssh/id_rsa


 - name: Create Digital Ocean Key
   community.digitalocean.digital_ocean:
     state: present
     command: droplet
     name: "" "{{ item }}"
     unique_name: yes
     size_id: s-1vcpu-1gb
     region_id: nyc
     image_id: centos-7-x64
     ssh_key_ids: "{{ my_ssh.ssh_key.id }}"
     api_token: "{{ digital_ocean_token }}"
   with_items: "{{droplets}}"
   register: droplet_details
 

 - name: Add doplets to /etc/ansible/hosts
   add_host:
     path: /etc/ansible/hosts
     groups: droplets
     name: "{{ item.droplet.ip_address }}"
   with_items:: "{{ droplet_details.results }}"

 - pause:
      seconds: 45

 - hosts: droplets
   tasks:

 - name: Disable SeLinux
   selinux:
     state: disabled

 #Epel-Release
 - name: Install epel-release
   yum:
     name: epel-release
     state: present

 - name: update
   yum:
     name: "*"
     state: present

#Install Apache
 - name: Install Apache
   yum:
     name: httpd
     state: latest

 - name: enable service to start on boot up
   service:
   name: httpd
   state: started

#Install MariaDB
 - name: Install MariaDB
   yum:
     name: mariadb
     state: latest

 - name: Install MariaDB Server
   yum:
     name: mariadb-server
     state: latest

 - name: Install Python2
   yum:
     name: python2
     state: latest

 - name: Install Python3
   yum:
     name: python3
     state: latest

 - name: Install pip
   pip:
     name: pip
     extra_args: --upgrade
     executable: pip3

#Install PHP
 - name: Install Remi Repository
   yum:
     name: https://rpms.remirepo.net/enterprise/remi-release-7.rpm
     state: present

 - name: Install PHP 
   yum:
     enablerepo: "remiremi-php80"
     name:
         - php
         - php-common
         - php-cli
         - php-gd
         - php-curl
         - php-mysqlnd
         - php-fpm
         - php-mysqli
         - php-json
   state:latest

 - name: Install MySQL repo
   yum:
     name: http://dev.mysql.com/get/mysql57-community-release-el7-8.noarch.rpm
     state: present

 - name: Install PyMySQL
   yum:
     pkg: ['mysql-community-server', 'mysql-community-client', 'MySQL-python']

# Start MySQL
 - name: Start MySQL
   service:
     name: mysqld
     state: started
     enabled: yes

# Create MariaDB Database
 - name: MySQL login
   mysql_user:
     user: ***
     login_user: ***
     login_password: "****"
     state: present

 - name: Create MariaDB username & password
   mysql_user:
     login_user: ****
     login_password: "****!"
     name: wordpressuser
     password: ****
     priv: "*.*;ALL,GRANT"
     host: "localhost"
     state: present

 - name: Vreate MariaDB Database
   mysql_db:
   login_user: ***
   login_password: "****"
   state: present

 - name: Restart MariaDB Database
   service:
     name: mysqld
     state: restarted                         

# Install Wordpress
 - name: Download Wordpress
   get_url:
     url=http://wordpress.org/latest.tar.gz
     dest=/tmp/wordpress.latest.tar.gz
     validate_certs=no

 - name: unzip Wordpress
   unarchive:
     src=/tmp/wordpress.latest.tar.gz
     dest=/var/www
     copy=no

 - name: Copy sample config file
   command: mv /var/www/wordpress/wp-config-sample.php /var/www/wordpress/wp-config.php

 - name: Update Wordpress config file
   lineinfile:
     path: /var/www/wordpress/wp-config.php
     regexp: "{{item.regexp}}"
     line: "{{item.line}}"
   with_items:
     - {'regexp': "define\\( 'DB_NAME', '(.)+' \\);", 'line': "define( 'DB_NAME'', 'wordpress');"}
     - {'regexp': "define\\( 'DB_USER', '(.)+' \\);", 'line': "define( 'DB_USER', 'wordpressuser' );"}
     - {'regexp': "define\\( 'DB_PASSWORD', '(.)+' \\);", 'line': "define( 'DB_PASSWORD', '***' );"}

 - name: Give Ownership to Apache user
   file:
     path: /var/www/wordpress
     state" directory
     recurse: yes
     owner: apache
     group: apache

 - name: Set correct permissions on Wordpress directories
   command: find /var/www/wordpress/ -type d -exec chomd 755 {} \;

 - name: Set correct permissions for Wordpress files
   command: find /var/www/wordpress/ -type f -exec chomd 755 {} \;

 - name: Restart Apache
   service:
     name: httpd
     state: restarted
```

Comment: Is that all you have?  That should be inside your tasks: section.

Comment: I have more. Let me add.

Comment: There are obvious YAML errors in that file that even the syntax highlighter of SO shows: `state:latest`; `state" directory`, maybe others. A good idea would be to use an IDE with support YAML syntax and those would just be red-colour screamed back at your by the editor.

Comment: Also, it would be a good idea to not mix `attribute=value`and the YAML `attribute: value` syntax, because you will end up with those kind of errors more frequently as the rules are different and so, you are just making it difficult for yourself. (e.g. spaces in `attribute=value` might bring odd results when no space in `attribute: value` is a syntax error, as you see it).

Answer (score 1):

It looks from what you provided that you don't have a valid yaml format playbook.

You can do quick syntax checks using:

`ansible-playbook playbook.yaml --syntax-check`

The plays need to be one or more elements of a yaml list, under tasks.

I'd expect your playbook to look something like:

```
---
# YAML documents begin with the document separator ---

- hosts: hosta,hostb ...etc
  
  tasks: 
    - name: install MySQL repo
      yum: 
        name: http://dev.mysql.com/get/mysql57-community-release-el7-8.noarch.rpm
        state: present

# Three dots indicate the end of a YAML document
...
```

There are other sections you might have in a playbook, but I've omitted those. The sections like vars, handlers or roles, would be list items at the same indention level as the hosts: and tasks: if you were to need those.

It looks like your issue is here:

```
  name: Install PHP 
  yum:
   enablerepo: "remiremi-php80"
   name:
         - php
         - php-common
         - php-cli
         - php-gd
         - php-curl
         - php-mysqlnd
         - php-fpm
         - php-mysqli
         - php-json
   state: latest
```

Notice that state: has to be indented exactly at the same level as enablerepo and name. Make sure you have a space there between state: and latest.

Comment: I added the whole thing so. you can get a better idea. May still be the same answer but not sure.

Comment: Looking at your full file, I think the problem is the task previous.  Compare mine to yours for the fix.

Comment: So  I have made some progress but now it's different and it's blowing my mind.

Comment: You have a lot of plays there ;)   I'm wondering why you are installing both mysql and mariadb though?

Comment: It was a requirement for some unknown reason which I am curious myself. I do now get a run somewhat but error out in the section of -name: Create DigitalOcean SSH key